# How to generate xml file with an existing dtd for sample of data using Java

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, dtd, jdom

I have some data stored in :

```
HashMap<Position, Double> listOfPoints = new HashMap<>();
```

Where key contains pair (x,y).

I have defined also my dtd file called generated.dtd which contains my structure :

```
<!ELEMENT table (point*,id,position,x,y,value)>
<!ELEMENT point (id,position,value)>
<!ELEMENT id (ID)>
<!ELEMENT position (x,y)>
<!ELEMENT value (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT x (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT y (#PCDATA)>
```

Using that file and sample of data stored in listOfPoints , I would like to **generate an xml file** that corresponds to my generated.dtd structure.

How could i do that in Java?

If you have a tutorial to follow , it will be great .

Iknow i should use JAXB : Java Architecture for XML Binding, but i don't know how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of observations/suggestions:

### 1) What do you need the XML  output to look like?

Assume you have a `Points` class like this:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
public class Points {

    public Points() {};

    public Points(Map<Position, Double> listOfPoints) {
        this.listOfPoints = listOfPoints;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "list_of_points")
    private Map<Position, Double> listOfPoints;

    public Map<Position, Double> getListOfPoints() {
        if (listOfPoints == null) {
            listOfPoints = new HashMap();
        }
        return this.listOfPoints;
    }
}
```

and a `Position` class like this:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "position")
public class Position {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String x;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String y;

    public String getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(String value) {
        this.x = value;
    }

    public String getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(String value) {
        this.y = value;
    }

}
```

Without using a DTD, you can generate XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <listOfPoints>
        <entry>
            <key>
                <x>pos1 x</x>
                <y>pos1 y</y>
            </key>
            <value>123.456</value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key>
                <x>pos2 x</x>
                <y>pos2 y</y>
            </key>
            <value>456.789</value>
        </entry>
    </listOfPoints>
</root>
```

The code to do that is:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Points.class);
Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
File xml = new File("/path/to/points.xml");
marshaller.marshal(points, xml);
```

Is that sufficient for your needs?

### 2) Using your DTD

I'm not sure how your DTD is going to help you, because it implies a set of unrelated and overlapping Java objects from which the final XML will be created.

To see what I mean, try it for yourself.

Using the `xjc` tool (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/xjc.htm)), you can generate Java objects from your DTD:

```
/path/to/jdk/bin/xjc -d output -p org.ajames.jaxbdemo.points -dtd my_schema.dtd
```

Using these Java classes, you can populate your data structure (your `listOfPoints`). And then you can create the XML output from that (as shown above, using the JAXB marshaller).

But your DTD will create some not-very-useful objects...

So, that comes back to the initial question: *What do you want your XML to look like?*

### 3) Use an XSD?

If you manually create a sample of your required XML, you can then generate an XSD from it. There are various [online tools](https://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html) to help with that. Then you can use the `xjc` command again (but this time for an XSD not a DTD). And then you can use the resulting Java objects to get the exact XML you need.

Comment: Thank you very mush , it is very helpfull.