# jaxb binding returning null value for nested map xml implementation

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jaxb

Sample of the xml being parsed

```xml
<llsd>
    <map>
    <key>agents</key>
        <map>
        <key>0008c41e-3298-449c-8abd-4929a0eeae0e</key>
            <map>
            <key>display_name</key>
                <string>kettelynin</string>
            <key>display_name_expires</key>
                <date>2020-06-24T23:53:44.05Z</date>
            <key>display_name_next_update</key>
                <date>1970-01-01T00:00:00Z</date>
            <key>is_display_name_default</key>
                <boolean>1</boolean>
            <key>legacy_first_name</key>
                <string>kettelynin</string>
            <key>legacy_last_name</key>
                <string>Resident</string>
            <key>username</key>
                <string>username1</string>
            </map>
        <key>000bd88c-562f-423e-af63-55b9f0b17e10</key>
            <map>
            <key>display_name</key>
                <string>ϯ Mary Baker Pitbull Darkϯ  </string>
            <key>display_name_expires</key>
                <date>2020-06-25T00:24:25.63Z</date>
            <key>display_name_next_update</key>
                <date>1970-01-01T00:00:00Z</date>
            <key>is_display_name_default</key>
                <boolean>0</boolean>
            <key>legacy_first_name</key>
                <string>maryunasilva</string>
            <key>legacy_last_name</key>
                <string>Resident</string>
            <key>username</key>
                <string>username2</string>
            </map>
        </map>
    </map>
</llsd>
```

As I understand it, the structure is some nested maps with String keys and with various Objects as the final values. So, I have this class.

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.util.Map;

@XmlRootElement
public class llsd {
    Map<String, Map<String, Object>> agents;

    llsd() {
    }

    public Map<String, Map<String, Object>> getAgents() {
        return agents;
    }
}
```

I'm running the following code snippet to test it

```java
JAXBContext newInstance = JAXBContext.newInstance(llsd.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshall = newInstance.createUnmarshaller();
llsd newParsed = (llsd) unmarshall.unmarshal(new File("C:/path/to/my.xml"));
```

I don't get any errors while running it, but when I run the debugger, I can see that the newParsed value for agents is null. Clearly I've got my binding set up wrong, but I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your XML has more nesting levels than accounted for by `Map<String, Map<String, Object>>`. You can take a look at some approaches suggested in other JAXB-related questions, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49181125/unmarshal-nested-xml-elements-with-jaxb) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25704853/unmarshalling-nested-list-of-xml-items-using-jaxb/25709312) for general approaches.

If you are not familiar with `xjc` that can also help you to build the objects needed by JAXB - see notes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61276167/12567365).

However, for a structure such as the specific one in your question, I would consider a different (non-JAXB) approach. One of the reasons is because your data has ordered pairs of tags, such as:

```
<key>display_name_expires</key>
<date>2020-06-25T00:24:25.63Z</date>
```

You have the field name in one tag, and then a related data type and value in the following tag. I don't know any clean way to handle this in JAXB (there may be a way, of course).

My alternative is to use Java's xPath classes to parse the XML in a targeted way, and to build a list of `Agent` data beans. It's a manual process, but fairly straightforward.

**The `Agent` Bean:**

```
import java.util.UUID;
import java.time.Instant;

public class Agent {

    private UUID id;
    private String displayName;
    private Instant displayNameExpires;
    private Instant displayNameNextUpdate;
    private boolean isDisplayNameDefault;
    private String legacyFirstName;
    private String legacyLastName;
    private String userName;

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }

    public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    public Instant getDisplayNameExpires() {
        return displayNameExpires;
    }

    public void setDisplayNameExpires(String displayNameExpires) {
        this.displayNameExpires = Instant.parse(displayNameExpires);
    }

    public Instant getDisplayNameNextUpdate() {
        return displayNameNextUpdate;
    }

    public void setDisplayNameNextUpdate(String displayNameNextUpdate) {
        this.displayNameNextUpdate = Instant.parse(displayNameNextUpdate);
    }

    public boolean getIsDisplayNameDefault() {
        return isDisplayNameDefault;
    }

    public void setIsDisplayNameDefault(String isDefault) {
        this.isDisplayNameDefault = isDefault.equals("1") ? Boolean.TRUE
                : Boolean.FALSE;
    }

    public String getLegacyFirstName() {
        return legacyFirstName;
    }

    public void setLegacyFirstName(String legacyFirstName) {
        this.legacyFirstName = legacyFirstName;
    }

    public String getLegacyLastName() {
        return legacyLastName;
    }

    public void setLegacyLastName(String legacyLastName) {
        this.legacyLastName = legacyLastName;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

}
```

In the above class, the only thing to note is the inclusion of data conversions in the relevant getters, from `String` to other types, where needed (instants and booleans).

**The XML Processor:**

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AgentReader {

    private final List<Agent> agents = new ArrayList();
    
    public void processAgents() throws FileNotFoundException, ParserConfigurationException,
            SAXException, IOException, XPathExpressionException {

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("/path/to/llsd.xml"));
        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(fis);
        xmlDocument.normalizeDocument();

        XPathExpression idPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath()
                .compile("/llsd/map/map/key");
        XPathExpression attrMapPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath()
                .compile("/llsd/map/map/map");
        // This is relative to the attrMapPath defined above:
        XPathExpression attrsPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath()
                .compile("./*");

        NodeList idNodes = (NodeList) idPath.evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        NodeList attrLists = (NodeList) attrMapPath.evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        for (int i = 0; i < idNodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Node idNode = idNodes.item(i);
            Node attrList = attrLists.item(i);
            agents.add(buildAgent(idNode, attrList, attrsPath));
        }
    }

    private Agent buildAgent(Node idNode, Node attrList, XPathExpression attrsPath)
            throws XPathExpressionException {
        Agent agent = new Agent();
        String id = idNode.getTextContent();

        NodeList attrNodes = (NodeList) attrsPath.evaluate(attrList, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        String fieldName = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < attrNodes.getLength(); i++) {
            // The data comes in pairs of tags - a field name and a related value:
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                fieldName = attrNodes.item(i).getTextContent();
            } else {
                String value = attrNodes.item(i).getTextContent();
                agent = addValue(fieldName, value, agent);
            }
        }
        return agent;
    }

    private Agent addValue(String fieldName, String value, Agent agent) {
        switch (fieldName) {
            case "display_name":
                agent.setDisplayName(value);
                break;
            case "display_name_expires":
                agent.setDisplayNameExpires(value);
                break;
            case "display_name_next_update":
                agent.setDisplayNameNextUpdate(value);
                break;
            case "is_display_name_default":
                agent.setIsDisplayNameDefault(value);
                break;
            case "legacy_first_name":
                agent.setLegacyFirstName(value);
                break;
            case "legacy_last_name":
                agent.setLegacyLastName(value);
                break;
            case "username":
                agent.setUserName(value);
                break;
        }
        return agent;
    }
}
```

In `processAgents()`, the xPaths allow us to ignore the outer nesting tags, and go directly to the data.

Because these tags are at the same level, we use 2 xPaths in parallel - one for the set of `<key>` tags, and one for the related set of `<map>` tags:

```
<key>0008c41e-3298-449c-8abd-4929a0eeae0e</key>
<map>...</map>
```

The related xPath selectors are `/llsd/map/map/key` and `/llsd/map/map/map`.

The assumption here is that there is always the same number of each tag (two of each in your sample). You could add some defensive coding to check this.

The `buildAgent()` method handles each set of data for one agent. It uses the switch statement in `addValue()` to call the relevant setter in the `Agent` bean.

The end result from your sample data is `List<Agent>` containing 2 objects.